# TeraData TPT API and SSIS

Tags: ssis, teradata

I just installed the Teradata 15.0 driver on one of the servers. Now I am able to connect to the TeraData DB and see all the drivers.
When I try to run the package, it complains that I am missing the TPT API. Fair enough. I downloaded the TTU 15.0 from the Teradata website and I am trying to follow

[http://www.attunity.com/forums/microsoft-ssis- teradata-connector/error-teradata-tpt-registry-key- cannot-1434.html](http://www.attunity.com/forums/microsoft-ssis-%20teradata-connector/error-teradata-tpt-registry-key-%20cannot-1434.html) article to recover from issues. 
I dont see the 1) Load and 2) Export TPT packages in there? What am I missing. I only want to install what is required and do not want to bloat my system. 
Please suggest what all I need to install so that I can pass it on to the DBA's who have admin rights on the system.

Thanks,

Comment: In newer releases of TPT there are only two packages: `tptstream` (only the stream operator) and `tptbase` (everything else including TPT API), so your installation should be fine. I can't help with that error, but you might track the registry access using Process Monitor: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645

Comment: Thanks @dnoeth. If you want to put this as the answer, I will gladly accept it. Thanks for the help.